# Custom LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry - InvalidCastException: 'Unable cast "Antlr.Runtime.Tree.CommonTree" to "NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, expression-trees

I make my own implementation of LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry for using specification pattern in my models. I can use specification with objects and query and do not repeat code (see sample). You can see all code [here](https://github.com/emejibka/nhibernate-specification). My code work fine with all cases except one. I got InvalidCastException if specification contains DateTime variable.

```cs
    public class Client
    {
        public static readonly Specification<Client> IsMaleSpecification = new Specification<Client>(x => x.Sex == "Male");

        public static readonly Specification<Client> IsAdultSpecification = new Specification<Client>(x => x.Birthday < DateTime.Today);

        [Specification(nameof(IsAdultSpecification))]
        public virtual bool IsAdult => IsAdultSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(this);

        [Specification(nameof(IsMaleSpecification))]
        public virtual bool IsMale => IsMaleSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(this);
    }

...
  var client = new Client() {Sex = "Male"};
  var isMale = client.IsMale; //true

  var maleCount = session.Query<Client>().Count(x => x.IsMale); //ok

  var adultCount = session.Query<Client>().Count(x => x.IsAdult);//exception
...
```

Exception

```
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.addrExprDot(Boolean root)
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.addrExpr(Boolean root)
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.expr()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.exprOrSubquery()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.comparisonExpr()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.logicalExpr()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.whereClause()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.unionedQuery()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.query()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectStatement()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.statement()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(String collectionRole)
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   в NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   в NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   в NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   в NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   в NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query)
   в NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   в NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   в System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   в ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\git\TestApp\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:строка 32
```

Why specification with any another type variables work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular problem is not the `DateTime` type, but the `DateTime.Today` method.

The general problem is that the HqlGenerators are called too late in the NHibernate LINQ query expression processing pipeline, so many parts of the original expression preprocessing like partial evaluation, parameterization etc. are missing there. The difference can easily be seen even with the "working" query - if you use directly `x => x.Sex == "Male"` inside the LINQ query, the SQL query is parameterized, while the translated SQL from `x => x.IsMale` uses constant literal.

What you are trying to achieve is basically replacing one expression with another inside expression tree, which is exactly what `ExpressionVisitor`s are for. And all you need is to be able to preprocess the query expression *before* the query provider.

Strangely, none of the major LINQ query providers (NHibernate, EF6, EF Core) provide a way to do that. But more on this later. Let me first show the method needed to apply the specifications (error checking omitted):

```
public static class SpecificationExtensions
{
    public static Expression ApplySpecifications(this Expression source) =>
        new SpecificationsProcessor().Visit(source);

    class SpecificationsProcessor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Expression != null && node.Member is PropertyInfo property)
            {
                var info = property.GetCustomAttribute<SpecificationAttribute>();
                if (info != null)
                {
                    var type = property.DeclaringType;
                    var specificationMemberInfo = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .Single(x => x.Name == info.FieldName);
                    var specification = (BaseSpecification)specificationMemberInfo.GetValue(null);
                    var specificationExpression = (LambdaExpression)specification.ToExpression();
                    var expression = specificationExpression.Body.ReplaceParameter(
                        specificationExpression.Parameters.Single(), Visit(node.Expression));
                    return Visit(expression);
                }
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
}
```

which uses the following helper:

```
public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression source, ParameterExpression from, Expression to)
        => new ParameterReplacer { From = from, To = to }.Visit(source);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression From;
        public Expression To;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) => node == From ? To : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Now the plumbing part. Actually NHibernate allows you to replace the LINQ provider with your own. In theory you should be able to create `DefaultQueryProvider` derived class, override the `PrepareQuery` method and preprocess the passed expression before calling the base implementation.

Unfortunately there is an implementation flaw of `IQueryProviderWithOptions.WithOptions` method in the `DefaultQueryProvider` class which requires some ugly reflection based hacks. But without that the query provider will be replaced with the default if the query is using some of the `WithOptions` extension methods, thus negating all our efforts.

With that being said, here is the provider code:

```
public class CustomQueryProvider : DefaultQueryProvider, IQueryProviderWithOptions
{
    // Required constructors
    public CustomQueryProvider(ISessionImplementor session) : base(session) { }
    public CustomQueryProvider(ISessionImplementor session, object collection) : base(session, collection) { }
    // The code we need
    protected override NhLinqExpression PrepareQuery(Expression expression, out IQuery query)
        => base.PrepareQuery(expression.ApplySpecifications(), out query);
    // Hacks for correctly supporting IQueryProviderWithOptions
    IQueryProvider IQueryProviderWithOptions.WithOptions(Action<NhQueryableOptions> setOptions)
    {
        if (setOptions == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(setOptions));
        var options = (NhQueryableOptions)_options.GetValue(this);
        var newOptions = options != null ? (NhQueryableOptions)CloneOptions.Invoke(options, null) : new NhQueryableOptions();
        setOptions(newOptions);
        var clone = (CustomQueryProvider)this.MemberwiseClone();
        _options.SetValue(clone, newOptions);
        return clone;
    }
    static readonly FieldInfo _options = typeof(DefaultQueryProvider).GetField("_options", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    static readonly MethodInfo CloneOptions = typeof(NhQueryableOptions).GetMethod("Clone", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

The classes `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry` and `SpecificationHqlGenerator` are not needed anymore, so remove them and replace

```
cfg.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();
```

with

```
cfg.LinqQueryProvider<CustomQueryProvider>();
```

and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Wow, this is great.  I've been looking for a solution to this problem for months!  I'm in the process of implementing it in my application and will happily upvote this as soon as I get it working.  Question:  Is there any reason why the expressions have to be Specifications, as opposed to any arbitrary Expression?  I need, for example, to compute properties of all types and have SQL generated from them.  Also, have you revisited later NH releases to see whether the awkward design you had to code around has been improved?

Comment: @Michael (1) No reason, just this was the concrete OP question. (2) No, I haven't watching Nh since then, recently I'm focused mainly on EF Core.

Comment: It worked!  I had to write a slightly different Attribute to handle arbitrary Expressions (as opposed to Specifications), but it worked!  Thank you.

Comment: `whether the awkward design you had to code around has been improved` In NHibernate 5.3 you can simply override `CreateWithOptions` method instead of implementing `IQueryProviderWithOptions.WithOptions` See https://gist.github.com/bahusoid/8976209947b8c5f371040eb85748078f